# Golang 1.8 plugin.Lookup only loads first plugin

Tags: go

I'm writing a [Rules Engine](https://github.com/patrobinson/go-fish) in Golang. My tests involve building and loading two plugins that do some very simple string comparison. I load the plugins by doing a fileglob and calling `plugin.Open()`, so far so good we get two different objects back. But when I call `plug.Lookup(symbol)` the symbol returned is always a reference to the first plugin.

```
DEBU[0000] Starting A rule

DEBU[0000] Starting A rule
```

I've debugged back to make sure the plugins are different objects, which they are, but the symbol lookup isn't working as expected.

Here's a contrived working example:

main.go
    package main

```
import "plugin"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    aPlug, _ := plugin.Open("testdata/plugins/a.so")
    aSymPlug, _ := aPlug.Lookup("Rule")
    fmt.Printf("Plugin: %v loaded\n", aSymPlug)

    bPlug, _ := plugin.Open("testdata/plugins/b.so")
    bSymPlug, _ := bPlug.Lookup("Rule")
    fmt.Printf("Plugin: %v loaded\n", bSymPlug)
}
```

a.go plugin

```
package main

type plugin string

func init() {
    Rule = "a"
}

func (p plugin) String() string {
    return string(p)
}

var Rule plugin
```

b.go plugin

```
package main

type plugin string

func init() {
    Rule = "b"
}

func (p plugin) String() string {
        return string(p)
}

var Rule plugin
```

BUT when I change the plugin to return the string "a" or "b" (doesn't matter which plugin, either or both) instead of `p` then it loads the wrong plugin! i.e.

```
package main

type plugin string

func init() {
    Rule = "b"
}

func (p plugin) String() string {
        return "b"
}

var Rule plugin
```

This outputs:

```
Plugin: a loaded
Plugin: a loaded
```

EDIT: Added example code

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: The full source is linked in the question. https://github.com/patrobinson/go-fish

Comment: Don't expect that everyone go to the project and look every file to see which part doesn't work, at least write an example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll put up a simpler example shortly

Comment: A way to fix the execution is use different types in each plugin like `type pluginA string` and `type pluginB string` to prevent  the type collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Golang bug (see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20376)

The workaround, as pointed out by [Motakjuq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7187655/motakjuq), is to change the name of the type so each plugin has a different type. This avoids the collision.